# Understand antlr4 generated parsercontext code, Find a good way to detect terminalNode in one context

Tags: java, antlr4

The part of G4 file is :

```
typeSpecifier
    :   ('void'
    |   'char'
    |   'short'
    |   'int'
    |   '__m128d'
    |   '__m128i')
    |   '__extension__' '(' ('__m128' | '__m128d' | '__m128i') ')'
    |   atomicTypeSpecifier
    |   structOrUnionSpecifier
    |   enumSpecifier
    |   typedefName
    |   '__typeof__' '(' constantExpression ')' // GCC extension
    ;
```

The generated code is :

```
public static class TypeSpecifierContext extends ParserRuleContext {                                                     
    public AtomicTypeSpecifierContext atomicTypeSpecifier() {                                                            
        return getRuleContext(AtomicTypeSpecifierContext.class,0);                                                       
    }                                                                                                                    
    public StructOrUnionSpecifierContext structOrUnionSpecifier() {                                                      
        return getRuleContext(StructOrUnionSpecifierContext.class,0);                                                    
    }                                                                                                                    
    public EnumSpecifierContext enumSpecifier() {                                                                        
        return getRuleContext(EnumSpecifierContext.class,0);                                                             
    }                                                                                                                    
    public TypedefNameContext typedefName() {                                                                            
        return getRuleContext(TypedefNameContext.class,0);                                                               
    }                                                                                                                    
    public ConstantExpressionContext constantExpression() {                                                              
        return getRuleContext(ConstantExpressionContext.class,0);                                                        
    }                                                                                                                    
    public TypeSpecifierContext(ParserRuleContext parent, int invokingState) {                                           
        super(parent, invokingState);                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                    
    @Override public int getRuleIndex() { return RULE_typeSpecifier; }                                                   
    @Override                                                                                                            
    public void enterRule(ParseTreeListener listener) {                                                                  
        if ( listener instanceof ProbeListener ) ((ProbeListener)listener).enterTypeSpecifier(this);                     
    }                                                                                                                    
    @Override                                                                                                            
    public void exitRule(ParseTreeListener listener) {                                                                   
        if ( listener instanceof ProbeListener ) ((ProbeListener)listener).exitTypeSpecifier(this);                      
    }                                                                                                                    
    @Override                                                                                                            
    public <T> T accept(ParseTreeVisitor<? extends T> visitor) {                                                         
        if ( visitor instanceof ProbeVisitor ) return ((ProbeVisitor<? extends T>)visitor).visitTypeSpecifier(this);     
        else return visitor.visitChildren(this);                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                    
}
```

I am tring to see which type is this typeSpecifier in my visit code:

```
TypeSpecifierContext typeSpecifier = ctx.typeSpecifier(); // ctx is parent context    
LOG.trace(String.format("typeSepcifier the start is %s the stop is %s" , typeSpecifier.getStart().getText()
                    , typeSpecifier.getStop().getText()));
```

I can get ouput like :

```
typeSepcifier the start is int the stop is int
```

I think this method is ugly, Can Antlr4 offer ways to implement methods like `instanceof IntTypeSpecifier` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the visitor design pattern to visit ANTLR's AST and process it so you don't even need to use instanceof.

```
final class Visitor extends YourGrammarParserBaseVisitor<String> { // The name of the base visitor should be <your grammar name> + 'ParserBaseVisitor'

    @Override
    public String visitTypeSpecifier(TypeSpecifierContext ctx) { // 'visit' + <name of the rule with the first letter to upper case>
        // Your code here

        return "the result";
    }

    // other visit methods for other rules
}
```

Call your visitor:

```
new Visitor.visit(new YourGrammarParser(/* weird ANTLR stuff */).typeSpecifier());
```

If you create a rule for the int type let's say:

```
typeSpecifier
    : intTypeSpecifier
    | // the other rules
    ;

intTypeSpecifier : 'int';
```

You will be able to make a visit method for an IntTypeSpecifierContext `visitIntTypeSpecifier` to easily handle an int type.

So the code should look like:

```
final class Visitor extends YourGrammarParserBaseVisitor<String> {

    @Override
    public String visitTypeSpecifier(TypeSpecifierContext ctx) {
        return super();
    }

    @Override
    public String visitIntTypeSpecifier(IntTypeSpecifierContext ctx) {
        return 'int'; // or ctx.getText()
    }

    // Rest of the rules
}
```

Now correct me because I am probably wrong, but you can directly call `getText` to see the typeSpecifier's type (TypeSpecifierContext extend RuleContext which provides this method).